# Irrlicht: how to convert a ISceneNode into a IMeshSceneNode?

Tags: c++, game-development, irrlicht

I have got a complex code that is fully loaded with references to ISceneNode objects. I would like to enable shadows for these. However, the function that let us enable shadows is addShadowVolumeSceneNode(), which is only available for the class IMeshSceneNode.

My question is, how do I convert a ISceneNode into a IMeshSceneNode in order to apply shadows to it?

ps: I know it is not possible to apply shadows to a ISceneNode: http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=42174

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast an `ISceneNode` pointer to an `IMeshSceneNode` pointer, **if it actually points to an IMeshSceneNode object**:

```
void AddShadowToSceneNodeIfPossible(ISceneNode* node)
{
    IMeshSceneNode* meshNode = dynamic_cast<IMeshSceneNode*>(node);
    if (meshNode)
    {
        meshNode->addShadowVolumeSceneNode(...);
    }
}
```

But the better solution would be to store `IMeshSceneNode` pointers as `IMeshSceneNode` pointers from the start.

Comment: Just one more question: under which condition **dynamic_cast<IMeshSceneNode*>(node)** fails? In my code (i mentioned above in my question) it fails the casting process ( i know that because I added an else {cout<<"hi!"} to your code snippet)

Comment: @PintoDoido It returns `nullptr` for any `ISceneNode*` that is not an `IMeshSceneNode*`. Not every  `ISceneNode*` is an `IMeshSceneNode*`, there's `IParticleSystemSceneNode*` or `ILightSceneNode*` or also `IShadowVolumeSceneNode*` which coincidentally gets created in `addShadowVolumeSceneNode`. And many other types more.

Comment: As I wrote it would be best to store pointers to the `IMeshSceneNode`s you create as `IMeshSceneNode*`, not as `ISceneNode*`, then you don't need any casting later.

Comment: @PintoDoido By the way, not all ISceneNode are IMeshSceneNode. You could very well have a scene node that doesn't render anything, so that makes sense that you can't apply shadow to a scene node unless it's actually rendering something.